# unable to run npm run test-coverage for react js project

Tags: reactjs, react-testing-library

I am not able to run npm run test-coverage command to find the coverage in my ReactJS project using typescript. It is giving me the error saying

`Nothing was returned from render. This usually means a return statement is missing. Or, to render nothing, return null.`

I have the following versions in my project:

```
@testing-library/jest-dom: ^4.2.4
@testing-library/react: ^9.5.0
@testing-library/user-event: ^7.1.2
@types/jest: ^24.9.1
@types/react: ^16.9.0
react: ^16.13.1
react-dom: ^16.13.1
react-scripts: ^3.4.1
react-router-dom: ^5.1.2
typescript: ^3.8.2
```

My scripts section is as follows:

```
test: react-scripts test
test-coverage: react-scripts test --coverage
test:watch: jest --watch
eject: react-scripts eject
lint: eslint --ext .js,.jsx,.ts,.tsx src --color
format: prettier --write src/**/*.{ts,tsx,scss,css,json}
isready: npm run format && npm run lint && npm run build
```

I have tried downgrading the react-scripts version to 3.4.0 as well but that also didnt help. Please help me resolve this issue.

Comment: Please include your scripts in package.json so we can see what your test-coverage script actually does.

Comment: @RobertMay Can you please guide me on how to add them? I am new to this actually :)

Comment: In your package.json, the same file from which you found your dependencies, you should have a "scripts" field. It's probably close to the top. Edit your question post to include that part of package.json, or if you can't find it, include the whole file.

Comment: @RobertMay I have updated the question and have added the scripts section. Please look into it and guide me with the same.

Comment: @RobertMay Sir please provide me the inputs on this